# i've had an error with my code, i'm trying to test something out for a future project but it keeps not working

Tags: java, eclipse

for some context i'm trying to make a program that tells you different things depending on your number input. For example: number '0' is hello, world! number '6' is goodbye and else is Jad this is all stuff that is placeholders the error that keeps showing up is

`java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=1][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E] in the console`

here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 6;

    if (a == 0) {
        System.out.println("hello, World");
    } else if (a == 6) {
        System.out.println("goodbye");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Jad");
    }

    Scanner userInput;
    userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = userInput.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You have " + userInput + " eggs");

}
```

Comment: You're printing the `Scanner` instance (`userInput`)

Comment: Ah, you meant to do `System.out.println("You have " + a + " eggs");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you typo the variable name, the last line should be:

```
System.out.println("You have " + a);
```

Answer (score 0):

"else if (a == 6)" do have a "if". you can not write "else if" without "if".

To solve this you can move the "else if" block outside the if block

Comment: how do i do this

Comment: You already seem to have an `if` statement. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=1][match valid=true][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E this one